# Android Studio: How to implement backbutton in ActionBar from Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm having trouble implementing a backbutton in the ActionBar in a Fragment. Since this is a Fragment I don't have access to getSupportActionBar(); and each time I use this, or similar code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
          actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

only results in NullPointerExceptions.

I've looked at numerous similar questions on StackOverflow but most of them are specified to **Activities** or **AppCompatActivities**, which do not work in Fragments. Using

> getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

only results in NullPointerExceptions. The other similar questions and answers have not helped me with this problem so I had to create a new topic.

This is where I get the error:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();

        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //This results in NullPointerException

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get this to work so I changed the structure of the View and made it to an Activity which has more support in dealing with this issue.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstance){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to receive supportActionBar.

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar!=null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu` now works great, thank you! But there seems to be something wrong with the `onOptionsItemSelected` since nothing is happening when the backbutton is pressed, it doesnt even go into the method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe, do you override onOptionsItemSelected in Activity? if onOptionsItemSelected return true in Activity then onOptionsItemSelected in Fragment will not be called.

Comment: I'm ready to answer your other additional questions.
If it answer to help you, then you can approve and vote for the answer.

Comment: I override onOptionsItemSelected in the Activity, so I just noticed that the funcionality of other ActionBar menuitems changed to be onBackPressed, but not on the intended backbutton

Comment: I suppose problem not relate to ActionBar. You can check it. Add simple Button to Fragment. In OnClickListner for  Button add {requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();}. If after click on Button fragment continue to live, then problem relate to work with SupportFragmentManager.

Comment: I would like this specific functionallity in the ActionBar to only apply to this Fragment, by adding it with `ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar!=null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }` will make it apply to the entire application

Comment: maybe in your task, you need to add fragments to BackStack

supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container_view, SimpleFragment())
    .addToBackStack("FirstFragment")
    .commit()

supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container_view, SimpleFragment())
    .addToBackStack("SecondFragment")
    .commit()

Comment: also you can add Tag to Fragment, when in supportFragmentManager will keep ExampleFragment, activity won't handle onOptionsItemSelected